# Call to /api/auth/session gives ECONNRESET - next-auth

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-auth

I'm relatively new to `next-auth` & `next` in general. We have an application which we are transitioning to using AWS Cognito for authentication. It's a **server side** rendered application & I know this as under `pages/_app.tsx` is `getInitialProps()`. The code being:

```js
import React from "react";
import App from "next/app";
import Router from "next/router";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import withRedux from "next-redux-wrapper";
import ReduxToastr from "react-redux-toastr";
import NProgress from "nprogress";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/node";
// import { setTokens } from "../util/tokens";
import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";
import { SessionProvider, getSession } from "next-auth/react";

import createStore from "../redux/store";
import { setSession } from "../redux/session";
import "semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css";
import "react-redux-toastr/lib/css/react-redux-toastr.min.css";
import "../styles/nprogress.css";
import "../styles/overrides.scss";
import "../styles/util.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { IdToken, CognitoTokens } from "../interfaces";

Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", () => {
    NProgress.start();
});
Router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", () => NProgress.done());
Router.events.on("routeChangeError", () => NProgress.done());

NProgress.configure({ showSpinner: false });

type tProps = {
    passport?: {};
};

class MyApp extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }: any) {
        debugger;
        let pageProps: tProps = {};
        const session = await getSession({
            req: ctx.req,
        }); // this calls '/api/auth/session'
        // let tokens: AuthTokens = {};

        if (ctx.isServer && ctx.query?.code) {
            const {
                AUTH_DOMAIN,
                COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
                COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
                BASE_URL,
            } = process.env;
            const { data }: { data: CognitoTokens } = await axios.post(
                `https://${AUTH_DOMAIN}/oauth2/token?client_id=${COGNITO_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=${BASE_URL}&code=${ctx.query.code}`,
            );
        }

        return { pageProps };
    }

    render() {
        debugger
        const { Component, pageProps, store }: any = this.props;

        return (
            <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                    <ReduxToastr
                        preventDuplicates
                        position="bottom-right"
                        transitionIn="fadeIn"
                        transitionOut="fadeOut"
                        timeOut={5000}
                        progressBar
                    />
                </Provider>
            </SessionProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default withRedux(createStore)(MyApp);
```

**`pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].ts`**

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CognitoProvider from "next-auth/providers/cognito";

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        CognitoProvider({
            clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
            issuer: process.env.COGNITO_ISSUER,
        }),
    ],
    debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? true : false,
});
```

There is authentication middleware defined for the API. The main reason for this is that we have a custom `permissions` attribute defined on a user in Cognito which defines what CRUD operations they can do in specific environments

**`server/index.ts`**

```js
import express from "express";
import next from "next";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import session from "express-session";
import connectMongodbSession from "connect-mongodb-session";

// Config
import { /* auth0Strategy, */ getSessionConfig } from "./config";

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT || "3000", 10);
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

// API
import authAPI from "./api/auth";
import accountsAPI from "./api/accounts";
import usersAPI from "./api/users";
import jobsAPI from "./api/jobs";
import awsAPI from "./api/aws";
import completedJobsAPI from "./api/completedJobs";

// middleware
import { restrictAccess, checkPermissions } from "./middleware/auth";

// Server
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
    const MongoDBStore = connectMongodbSession(session);
    const store = new MongoDBStore({
        uri: process.env.MONGO_PROD_URL,
        collection: "godfatherSessions",
    });

    server.use(bodyParser.json());
    server.use(session(getSessionConfig(store)));

    server.get("/healthcheck", async (req: any, res, next) => {
        const { db } = req.session.req.sessionStore;

        try {
            await db.command({
                ping: 1,
            });

            res.status(200).end();
        } catch (err) {
            next(err);
        }
    });

    // Middleware
    server.use(checkPermissions);

    // API
    server.use(authAPI);
    server.use(accountsAPI, restrictAccess);
    server.use(usersAPI, restrictAccess);
    server.use(jobsAPI, restrictAccess);
    server.use(awsAPI, restrictAccess);
    server.use(completedJobsAPI, restrictAccess);

    // Protected Page Routes
    server.get("/accounts", restrictAccess, (req: any, res) =>
        app.render(req, res, "/accounts", req.query),
    );
    server.get("/users", restrictAccess, (req: any, res) =>
        app.render(req, res, "/users", req.query),
    );
    server.get("/jobs", restrictAccess, (req: any, res) =>
        app.render(req, res, "/jobs", req.query),
    );
    server.get("/completedJobs", restrictAccess, (req: any, res) => {
        app.render(req, res, "/completedJobs", req.query);
    });

    server.get("/debug-sentry", function mainHandler() {
        throw new Error("My first Sentry error!");
    });

    // Fallback Routes
    server.all("*", handle as any);

    // The error handler must be before any other error middleware and after all controllers
    // server.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());

    server.listen(port, (err?: Error) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(
            `> Server listening at http://localhost:${port} as ${
                dev ? "development" : process.env.NODE_ENV
            }`,
        );
    });
});
```

**`server/middleware/auth.ts`**

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/camelcase */
import "cross-fetch/polyfill";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import { ForbiddenError } from "../../util/errors";
import { Environments } from "../../interfaces";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { CognitoUser, CognitoUserPool } from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

export async function checkPermissions(
    req: CustomRequest,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction,
) {
    const { path, method } = req;
    const { authorization, env } = req.headers;
    const session = await getSession({ req });

    debugger;

    if (
        !req.url.includes("/api/") ||
        ["/api/auth/callback/cognito", "/api/auth/session"].includes(req.path)
    ) {
        return next();
    }

    if (req.headers.env === "development") {
        return next();
    }
    console.log(session);

    if (!authorization) {
        return res.status(401).redirect("/login");
    }
    const decoded: any = jwt_decode(authorization);
    const invalidAuth = isInvalidAuth(decoded, path);

    if (!invalidAuth) {
        const userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
            UserPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
            ClientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
        });
        const username = decoded.username || decoded["cognito:username"];
        const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser({
            Username: username,
            Pool: userPool,
        });
        const userAttributes: any = await getUserAttributes(cognitoUser);
        const permissions = userAttributes.permissions
            .split(",")
            .map(perm => `"${perm}"`);
        const hasPermission = getHasPermission(
            method,
            permissions,
            env as Environments,
        );

        if (!hasPermission) {
            return res
                .status(403)
                .send(
                    new ForbiddenError(
                        "You do not have permission to perform this action.",
                    ).toErrorObject(),
                );
        }

        return next();
    }
    return next(invalidAuth);
}
```

The callback URL defined in Cognito app client is "http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/cognito" *(for development purposes - as is highlighted in the [example](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/cognito))*.

When running the application & logging in via the Cognito hosted UI, the 1st breakpoint hit is the debugger on L5 in `checkPermissions`. The `session` is null at this point & the path is `/api/auth/session`.

The issue comes when I step through past that breakpoint to `return next()` where I get the error(s) shown in the picture below. So these are `ECONNRESET` errors & if I let it run freely, these errors occur over & over again resulting in an `EMFILE` error every now & again until eventually the application crashes. No other breakpoints are hit.

Versions:

- `next`: v9.3.5
- `next-auth`: v4.1.0

Even though, *by default*, `next-auth` will use localhost:3000, I kept getting an `ENOTFOUND` error when I didn't define the URL in the .env so I set it to:

```
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://127.0.0.1:3000
```

After reading all docs & examples & several tutorials on how to do it *(no one has done a tutorial on v4 - just v3)* I'm still stumped

[image]

Comment: Hey, what's up? Did you solve it? :)

Answer (score 0):

For me helped to remove `.next/` and add these lines to `.env`

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED="0"
NEXTAUTH_URL="http://127.0.0.1:3000"
NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL="http://127.0.0.1:3000"
```

It seems to work very fine.